# NextJS - Styled jsx is missing in the out directory

Tags: css, next.js

I have a very simple project in NextJs. I want to serve the files via NginX

These are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.80.2"
  }
```

My routes js

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();


module.exports = routes;
```

I have a common layout for entire application as shown here. Note the style jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Head from 'next/head';


const Layout = (props) => {

    return(
        <Container style={{margin:'30px', 'backgroundColor':'#fff','borderRadius': '5px'}}>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <style jsx global>{`
                      body { 
                        background: #202020;
                        font: 11px;
                      }

                      div.container {
                        margin: 30px;
                        padding-bottom: 2px;
                      }                                   
                    `}</style>              
            </Head>
            <Header />
            <div className='container'>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </Container>
    );

};

export default Layout;
```

All other pages would use this layout.

```
render() {
        return(
            <Layout>
                      <div>
                                          my app
                              </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
```

With Dev server, layout's styled jsx is getting applied properly. everything works just great.

If i do, npm run build & export and use the out content for static hosting, styled jsx is completely missing.

I also found that the `out` directory has index.html which is NOT serving the css. If use the index/index.html css is fine.

Again what is the right approach?

Comment: Hey, are you able to provide a working example? Perhaps using https://codesandbox.io? They already have Next.js support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `<style jsx>` tag outside `<Head>`. Basically all `styled-jsx` styles need to be a children element of the root.

[Here's the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvq4157xxp)

Simply download it (*by clicking at the middle-top-left - there is a button to download*).

```
<Container>
  <Head>
   ...
  </Head>
  <div className="container">{props.children}</div>
  <style jsx global>{`
    body {
      background: #202020;
      font: 11px;
    }

    container {
      margin: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
  `}</style>
</Container>
```

Here's some other useful info about `styled-jsx` that might help you better manage the styles:

- [Dynamic Styles](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#dynamic-styles)
- [External Styles](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#external-styles)
- [Styles outside components](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#styles-outside-of-components)

Also take into account that `styled-jsx` is not the only CSS-in-JS library out there. I personally prefer `styled-components`, you should check it out. [Here's an example on how to implement it with Next.js.](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. such a small mistake made me go crazy for couple of days. StackOverflow does not let me award you the 100 points.!! looks like we need to wait!